# Black and White Emojis Showing up on Outlook Website

Tags: outlook.com, firefox, windows

I have a client I am working with who has the Windows 7 black and white emojis showing up instead of the colour emojis you'd normally expect to display. The client has no problem in Gmail using the same web browser. Both Firefox 64 and IE 11.0.9866.19230 that they have on their computer seem to have the same problem on the Outlook site. Her emojis still show up in colour fine for others who she sends messages to, just not for her.

Is this a Outlook issue, or is there something wrong on the Windows 7 machine that they can do to fix things?

I've already had them clear their cache/cookies on their browser.

Comment: This question was migrated from superusers but I am not sure if this is actually related to web applications and more seems computer related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be by design. Please refer to [this article](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/emoji-support-in-outlook):
To see the colorful emoji versions in Outlook, you will need Windows 10 or Windows 8.1 (partial support).

When using Windows 7, you can insert the black and white version via the Segoe UI Symbol font. If the recipient supports colorful emoji, the colorful version will still be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I found when composing a new email there are 2 smiling emoji icons at the bottom of my email page:

1. The standard one we click on and get the black and white emojis (smiling face)
2. Another one just to the right of it (laughing face)

When I clicked on either of them, I still got black and white emojis; however, to the right of the "laughing" emoji there are three dots "..." (aka an ellipsis); when I clicked on the ellipsis a menu popped up with a selection at the bottom called "Get Add-ins". I clicked on the "Get Add-ins" option and on the new screen was able to do a search using the word "emoji". The search offered up an add-in called "Emoji". I clicked the "add" button provided, which installed the "Emoji" add-in. After that, I composed an email, but instead of clicking on the "smiling" emoji at the bottom (only gives black & white emojis), I tried clicking the "laughing" emoji (just to the right of it), and this time a new screen popped up to the right side of the email showing lots of emoji selections in COLOR, instead of the boring black and white default ones. I'm running Windows 7 and am using the email provided on Outlook.com.